Is it possible to train a neural network to feed into a Random Forest Classifier or any other type of classifier like XGBoost or Decision Tree?
I want to create a model architecture to predict future stock price movement as such:

The Goal of this model is to predict if the price will go UP or DOWN within the next 3 months.
I have tried a few models such as Logistic Regression, a Neural network, XGBoost, etc. Ive received some decent results. Through using a Random Forest Classifier I have received the best results so far. How can I encode data through using a neural network then pass those values to a Random Forest Classifier to make the classification rather than using a final output layer using a sigmoid function as shown in the picture(Using Python, Keras, and SKlearn).
I am not the most well versed in Keras so I want to know if it is even possible to train a neural network that feeds into a separate classifier and if so how would it be done.

This is maybe theoretically possible, but it's very hard. If you train it all at once, you have to figure out a way to backpropagate loss through the decision tree, which will be hard because they're not differentiable. If you train the neural net first, then the tree, you have to come up with some objective for the neural net to maximize which coincidentally creates features which are helpful to the decision tree.

Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com. That said, my advice is to try to predict the price change (i.e., a continuous output), or, better yet, a distribution over price changes. Then look at decisions you can make assuming the price change is some amount, and weight the cost or benefit by the probability of that amount.

You need to use AutoEncoder for dimensionality reduction. You could take a look here.
The steps in simplified form would be the following:

Train an AutoEncoder
Take the encoder part
Encode your data with the encoder
Train another model of your choice with encoded data

If you are uncomfortable with keras or pytorch, you can even use scikit-learn MLPClassifier.

Do you think that It would work best to use a AutoEncoder or to modify it to attempt to predict the target variable and then take the features from the layer before the final class prediction. Then use that value to pass to a decision tree or some other classifier.  Or do you think it would be best to stick to a standard AutoEncoder

I don't have strict answer you may try the both. Per me it should be better than taking the layer before prediction. For the following reasons: other models may learn the function of the last layer of neural network, leading small difference. However, your suggestion looks like transfer learning, not sure whether it is applicable for different model types. Meanwhile, in AutoEncoder case, it will learn the important features and will remove the noise, so may lead better result. But in general for stock price prediction I'd probably use time series prediction techniques, such as RNN.

I am attempting to predict price movement in the next 3 months (Quarterly) hence why I am using quarterly financial data. Using any form of time series prediction technique has not produced any better results than using a normal NN. Maybe using a RNN for time series data like price, volume, and other technical indiactors in parallel with the financial data will produce better results.
